# Can you please explanation why ssh hostname on zsh for macOS requires a script?

Tags: zsh, macos

I have an M1 MacBook Pro running macOS 12.1.  I'm using the default zsh shell.  I've configured my `/etc/hosts` and my `~/.ssh/config` just like I had done when macOS was using bash.
When I go to ssh into a remote host I type `ssh <first few letters of the hostname> [tab]` In bash the hostname tab completion fills in the rest of the hostname. In zsh 5.8.1 it does not.  From what I've read the work around is to use a script.

What I'd like to know is why does the version of zsh used by macOS 12.1 not have tab completion for ssh hostnames by default like in bash?

Comment: It sounds like your `zsh` autocomplete settings simply need to be adjusted to inspect your userspace SSH client configuration file

Comment: You may not have enabled completion properly. Try running `autoload compinstall; compinstall` again. In any case, I can't see how *using a script* would help in any way.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I went into ```_ssh``` and with my skills couldn't sort out how to make the changes.
@StéphaneChazelas I can't either.  I will commented out the entries I added to my zshrc and try your solution. 

I did find a solution that added entries to my ```.zshrc``` that solved the problem.
Problem solved but my question still stands as to why this isn't the default when versions of macOS that use zsh.

Comment: That would be a question for the maintainer of the `zsh` implementation for MacOS you are using.